# Sketches of stable 6-pointed curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-space

I was wondering if I could ask about stable $n$-pointed curves (essentially intersecting copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$ with at least $3$ special points on each copy - these may be either a point of intersection or a marked point).

I was wondering whether someone could perhaps help me by sketching out the possible cases for stable $6$-pointed curves? I have found all the cases possible for $5$ marked points (see sketch below), but I lose track in terms of the types of intersections that may occur for $3$ components and beyond in the case of $6$ marked points.

I have for $n=6$:

1 component: analogous to $n=5$

2 components: $2$ potential cases (distributing the marks by $2,4$ or $3,3$).

3 components: where I find difficulty.

[[image: all possible cases for <span class=]$n=5$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBrfK.jpg)

Would it be possible to construct the same sketch but for the case $n=6$?

Thanks you very much in advance!

Comment: The only way to have a $3$ component rational nodal curve is as you've drawn in the $n=5$ case. Notice that this $5$-pointed curve is unique up to isomorphism because each component has exactly $3$ special points. So to get the possible $6$-pointed curves, simple place the final marking on any of the three components.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Tabes Bridges! I was confused about whether there were alternative formulations aside from that which you described.

What about for 4 components? Are there multiple configurations? Can a 6-pointed curve with 5 components exist?

Comment: If you drop the 6th point $p$ on either of the "external" components and let it collide with a marked point $q$, the stable limit is a chain of 4 $\mathbb P^1$s. The new $\mathbb P^1$ will be attached at the point where $q$ was, and $p$ and $q$ will both move onto the new component. If, on the other hand, you let $p$ collide with the intersection point, you still get a chain of 4 $\mathbb P^1$s, but the new component appears at the intersection point where the collision took place, and $p$ moves onto this new component...

Comment: ...Finally, if you put $p$ on the internal component $C_0$, you can either let it collide with the intersection point, which results in the same limit as before, or let it collide with the unique marked point $r\in C_0$. In this case, you get a new component sticking out of $C_0$ from the point that was previously labeled $r$ (now $r$ and $p$ are on the new component), so you have a new type of configuration with $C_0$ as the "central component" and the other three sticking out of it....

Comment: ...Now, note that all of these configurations have exactly three special points per component, so they are unique up to isomorphism. In general, $\dim \overline M_{0,n} = n-3$, and strata parametrizing configurations with $k$ nodes have codimension $k$. So any time $n-3=k$ (i.e. here $n=6$ and $k=3$) you have reached the curves which are as degenerate as possible while still being stable, so you cannot go any further.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tabes Bridges! This has been very helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

I think I've found the sketches for stable $6$-pointed curves. I was getting confused as I was forgetting the no closed circuits condition.

Thanks to @Tabes Bridges for their help!

[image]

Comment: Yep, this looks right to me!